# iOS8: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification while app is in background

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios8, uideviceorientation

I'm using following code to get device orientation change notifications.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

My application runs in background also.

- The notification works fine when application is running in
  foreground.
- If application is in foreground and device is locked then `[[UIDevice
  currentDevice] orientation]` always return Portrait orientation and
  before locking a orientation change notification is thrown.
- But when application goes in background then notification stops.
  And afterwards `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`will always return the orientation that it measured lastly in active state.

Can someone tell me why notification stops when my app goes in background state where device is still being used(by other apps)? I'm collecting all the orientation change events so I need the device to send me events while app is is foreground or background.

Comment: It's because you don't need to change interface when your application is in background, and this Notification exists only for interface changes when device is rotated.

Comment: But it's a device-level notification like music app notifications which you can reccieve in background. Although you're right that I can't do anything in background. and it's working in ios8.0. It stopped working in iOS8.3